# How to disable mouse copy while keeping mouse scroll in tmux?

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I'm running tmux via ssh on a linux (remote) machine from an iTerm2 on macOS.

I've configured `.tmux.conf` in order to get mouse wheel scrolling inside of tmux via the following:

`set -g mouse on`

This enables mouse wheel scrolling, copy to clipboard on mouse drag and others.

Can I keep mouse wheel scrolling but disable copy on mouse drag to clipboard at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the best behaviour I was able to get from `tmux` so far

```
set -g mouse on
unbind-key MouseDown2Pane
unbind-key MouseDragEnd1Pane
bind-key -n MouseDown2Pane run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel primary)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
bind-key -T copy-mode MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -sel primary -i"
set -g set-clipboard external
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `tmux list-keys` you should see lines like

```
bind-key    -T root         MouseDrag1Pane ...
```

depending on your version of tmux. You can add lines to your config file to unbind the ones you don't want, eg:

```
unbind-key -T root MouseDrag1Pane
```

Comment: Hi, tried what you suggested and this solution is blocking the mouse drag operation entirely which means that I cannot select text in iTerm2 at all :( I'd like to find a way how to use the iTerm's native text selection. Thanks!

Comment: have you been able to fix this? having the same annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

When tmux has the mouse mode on (set -g mouse on), then in iTerm on macOS you can press the option key (= alt key) to temporary disable sending mouse events to the terminal application (and thus you can mark lines in the terminal as you are used to).

This also allows you to scroll back in your buffer to before you started tmux.